# Rails: Setting Up Stripe Webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, stripe-payments, webhooks

I have stripe all set accepting payments and the [stripe_event](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event) gem installed.  In the docs for the gem it says to just do something like this in routes.rb:

```
mount StripeEvent::Engine => '/stripe'
```

but that is failing to show anything at that route. What else do I need to do to get the webhook working in my development environment?  Is it even possible?  (I did set the stripe webhook to be sent to 0.0.0.0:3000 but I am sure that is wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Is it not showing up in `rake routes`?

Comment: It comes up as: stripe_event        /stripe                          StripeEvent::Engine when I run rake routes.  Shouldn't I be able to view it as well?

Comment: it's a POST route, so it'll only be accessible via POST

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The webhook endpoint you set with Stripe needs to be a live url, not 0.0.0.0 or localhost. The routes appear to be setup correctly. You can test locally using curl:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -d '{"id":"evt_REPLACEME"}' localhost:3000/your-webhook-path
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else trying to receive webhooks on localhost with a Rails application I highly recommend this tool I just came across. Setup and running in seconds:

http://www.ultrahook.com